# L'Hopital mistake in $\frac{x^3+x-2}{x^2-3x+2}$

Tags: calculus, limits

What is the mistake in the aplication of L'Hopitale rule:

$\lim_{x\to 1}$ $\frac{x^3+x-2}{x^2-3x+2}$ = $\lim_{x \to 1}$ $\frac{3x^2+1}{2x-3}$ = $\lim_{x\to 1}$ $\frac{6x}{2}$ = $3$?

I have to solve this, I try:

$\frac{x^3+x-2}{x^2-3x+2}$ =$\frac{(x^2+x+2)(x-1)}{(x-2)(x-1)}$ =$\frac{(x^2+x+2)}{(x-2)}$ but lim of this function is $-4$ and the first one have no limit.

So I could not say why is wrong.

Any ideas?

Comment: The second application is wrong. You cannot apply L'Hopital when the limit is not indeterminate.

Comment: yes apply the limit at $\frac{3x^2+1}{2x-3}$ the answer is -4. no need to apply LH rule again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You apply L'Hopital rule only when you see indeterminate form of type $\frac{0}{0}$ or $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$. There are other forms as well. For the above problem, you have to do it the following way:

$\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{x^3+x-2}{x^2-3x+2}$, [$\frac{0}{0} form] $
=  $\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{3x^2+1}{2x-3} = \frac{4}{-1} = -4$.
That matches with your second approach.

Answer (score 3):

The second limit, $\lim_{x\rightarrow 1} \frac{3x^2 + 1}{2x - 3}$ is not of the form $"\frac{0}{0}"$ or $"\frac{\infty}{\infty}"$, so L'hospital's rule cannot be applied. It is equal to $-4$.

Comment: Please edit: $\frac{3x^2+1}{2x-1}$.

Answer (score 2):

The quotient $$\frac{3x^2+1}{2x-3}$$ is not undetermined at $x=1$: it equals $4/(-1)=-4$.